# File creation issues on node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having issues generating files with node. The files show up out of sequence and after the loop that has created them finish throwing my automated git commits of out whack. Can someone help me please! github repo: https://github.com/wendellmva/cli3

```
class Generator {
    constructor(){
        this.root = resolve(__dirname, 'generated');
    }   

    clean(done){
        if(fs.existsSync(this.root)){
            trash(this.root).then(done);
        } else {
            done();
        }
    }

    execute(){
        this.init()
        for(let i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            const file = resolve(this.root, `file${i}.txt`);
            fs.writeFile(file, 'Hello world', (err)=> {
                if(err) console.error(err);
                console.info('CREATE ', file);
                if(fs.existsSync(file)) this.add(file);
                if(i==9) this.commit();
            });
        }

    }

    init(){
        shelljs.exec(`mkdir ${this.root} && cd ${this.root} && git init`);
    }
    add(file){
        shelljs.exec(`cd ${this.root} && git add ${file}`);
    }
    commit(){
        shelljs.exec(`cd ${this.root} && git commit -m "chore: initial commit"`);
    }
}

const generator = new Generator();

generator.clean(()=>{
    generator.execute();
});
```

problem 1: commit starts before execute has finished
resulting in empty commit

problem 2: when generated files exist execute starts before clean has finished 
resulting in file already exist errors
===> SOLVED

problem 3: files are created out of sequence

```
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/@cardstrip/cli3/generated/.git/
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file2.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file3.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file0.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file1.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file4.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file5.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file7.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file9.txt
[master (root-commit) 3442284] chore: initial commit
8 files changed, 8 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 file0.txt
create mode 100644 file1.txt
create mode 100644 file2.txt
create mode 100644 file3.txt
create mode 100644 file4.txt
create mode 100644 file5.txt
create mode 100644 file7.txt
create mode 100644 file9.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file6.txt
CREATE  D:\@cardstrip\cli3\generated\file8.txt
```

Comment: Use https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `fs.writeFile` and `child_process.exec` are asynchronous, and you're not waiting until the operations are concluded, that's why your code is not doing what you expect it to do.

We can convert `writeFile` and `exec` to Promise based API with `util.promisify`, and use `async/await` to perform the operations in the right order.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const writeFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const exec = promisify(childProcess.exec);


class Generator {
    constructor(){
        this.root = resolve(__dirname, 'generated');
    }   

    async execute() {
        await this.init();

        for(let i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
            const file = resolve(this.root, `file${i}.txt`);

            await writeFile(file, 'Hello world');

            // No need to check if it exists, if it wasn't created writeFile rejects            
            console.info('CREATE ', file);

            await this.add(file);

        }

        return this.commit();
    }

    init(){
        return exec(`mkdir ${this.root} && cd ${this.root} && git init`);
    }

    add(file){
        return exec(`cd ${this.root} && git add ${file}`);
    }

    commit(){
        return exec(`cd ${this.root} && git commit -m "chore: initial commit"`);
    }
}
```

And now when doing:

```
new Generator()
   .execute()
   .then(() => console.log('Commited!')
   .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You will get your files created & added in order, and then the changes will be commited.

Comment: The doc for [shelljs.exec](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback) states that it is synchronous unless specified or given a callback

Comment: @PierreC. OP never specified he's using a third party, so I assumed `childProcess.exec` is being used, he has no reason to add a third party for a simple `.exec`. And in my answer I state that `childProcess.exec` is async, which it is.

Comment: It sure is, but as the OP does not use it, it is pretty irrelevant to answer the question. Another point I can make is that the OP seems to not quite understand callbacks yet. Introducing promises and await/async in his code might be too much (even if it is interesting).

Comment: He never state he's using shelljs lib, I can do: `const shelljs = require('child_process')`, if the info isn't in the question, I assume he's using the native API. `async/await` is easier than callbacks, so yes, I don't think it is too much, and it is way better than using the syncrhonous API, which is what you're using.

Comment: Fair enough. My take on SO answers is to go for the solution that changes the code as little as possible to make it simple for the OP. I guess we have different view on that and it is fine :) Have nice day

Comment: I had also a branch with await/async which I modified. I am indeed using shelljs since it wires up stdout. I wrapped my writefile and shelljs.exec in promisify from util and it all magically worked as expected. My great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the async version of `fs.writeFile` in a loop which means that you do not know the order in which the data will be written to disk and also that the loop will not wait for every call of that async function to continue.

You have to find a way to know when the last file has been written. A way to do that is to use the synnchronized version of the `fs.writeFile` function which is [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) this way :

```
execute(){
    this.init();

    for(let i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        const file = resolve(this.root, `file${i}.txt`);
        try {
            fs.writeFileSync(file, 'Hello world');
            console.info('CREATE ', file);

            if(fs.existsSync(file)) this.add(file);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
    this.commit();
}
```